# Execjs to Execute nodejs code from Ruby with some extra node_module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ruby, node-modules

I have ruby on rails env I like to execute nodejs command from my rails application.

I able to execute below scrip and it's works

```
require 'execjs'
context = ExecJS.compile('function double(x) { return x * 2 }')
puts context.call('double', 10)
```

now i like to use some extra node module to use.

```
context = ExecJS.compile('var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();client.on('connect', function() {    console.log('Redis client connected');});
             function selectdb(number) { client.select(number);}')

        context.call('selectdb', 1)
```

it gives me an error on require block that we not inject external node module.

is there any way I can inject extra module on my runtime code block.

I see some solution/workaround with stitch-rb but it not works.
please suggest if I am doing something wrong or any another way to use nodejs code from Rails application.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this, at least not with the vanilla implementation of `ExecJS`. (a suggested alternative is using [commonjs.rb](https://github.com/cowboyd/commonjs.rb))

Check the [FAQ here](https://github.com/rails/execjs#faq):

> Why can't I use CommonJS require() inside ExecJS?
>
> ExecJS provides a lowest common denominator interface to any
>   JavaScript runtime. Use ExecJS when it doesn't matter which JavaScript
>   interpreter your code runs in. If you want to access the Node API, you
>   should check another library like commonjs.rb designed to provide a
>   consistent interface.